# Efficiency: setting a var or calling method?

Tags: php

Would it be more efficient to declare a var:

```
$datetime = Carbon::now();
```

and use the var in a method twice:

```
$toDate < $datetime && $fromDate > $datetime
```

Or set no var and call something like Carbon::now() twice:

```
$toDate < Carbon::now() && $fromDate > Carbon::now()
```

Comment: If Carbon::now() is expensive enough to actually worry about this, then definitely only call it once. If it's not that expensive, it doesn't really matter. If you're really concerned you'll have to profile it.

Comment: what is Carbon::now by the way?

Comment: Basically, you could up with two different `Carbon::now()` using the second alternative.

Comment: I think the biggest problem with the latter solution is that probably (I assume that) `Carbon.now()` outputs a time and due to calling it twice you might experience race conditions. E.g. your code looking like: `$toDate < 1246820 && $fromDate > 1246830`

Comment: I just benchmarked on my machine and a million iterations of `Carbon::now()` takes 2.620 seconds. 2.62 microseconds per iteration probably fits solidly in the "doesn't matter" territory performance-wise.

Comment: BTW: From the carbon docs you can call `$datetime->gt($toDate)` and `$datetime->lt($fromDate)` https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-comparison

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would follow the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle and follow the first solution:

```
$datetime = Carbon::now();
if ($toDate < $datetime && $fromDate > $datetime) ...
```

In theory, method calling could be slightly more expensive due to pushing/popping context from the stack. However, I think the difference is negligible.

Someone brought up a valid point about race conditions that could occur if you call `now()` method twice. The second call may return a different value than the first call.

Answer (score 0):

The answer and almost everything in the programming world depends on 2 things- Time and Space and every programmer has to choose one between them when it comes to optimisation.

These 2 things are the time taken to execute a program and Space (memory) used during the execution.

So your question which is whether to save the value of Carbon::now() in a variable or call it directly depends on what you want to optimise. Time or the space.

If your php script would have been very long i.e. took more time, then it is good to call the function once and save its value to save execution time i.e. use -
    $datetime =Carbon::now();

Whereas, if you wanted your program to minimise the usage of memory, which seems obvious for servers because they need to respond to multiple requests simultaneously, you can directly call the method.

But again, you can optimise only one thing either time or memory. So choose the one that you want to achieve.